# Android wrong icons size on emulator

Tags: android

I've saved in my application the different size icons for each folder drawable -hdpi -mdpi -xhdpi and xxhdpi. I'm trying to create a bottom bar in my layout that has buttons with icons, but the icons are too small for the text. I know it says 18dp in the title of the image but they have different sizes, I've checked.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"   
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.work.MainActivity" >

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:editable="true" />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar">

    <Button android:id="@+id/b1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_text_format_white_18dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="ok" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/b2" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_text_format_white_18dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="cancel" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: And what are the sizes?

Comment: Do you mean they are showing up as different sizes on different devices, or that they're too small? Because an 18dp icon is a very small icon.

Comment: they are very small compared to the text? Is it beacause i've choosed to download the 18dp? The icons I've put in xhdpi looked big